# Run-Time error 438 - Dynamic Range VLookup Macro

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I want to create a VBA macro that will perform vlookups where the data source is on one sheet and the cell population is on another. The data source and cell population are on dynamic ranges. The following is what I have so far, and I am receiving Run-time error 438 on the "For Each cl In ws" line.

```
'***Vlookup for a dynamic range where the range and cell population are on different sheets.***

Sub mylookup3()

Dim startCell As Range
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim OppRow As Long
Dim OppClm As Long

'Dynamic ranges for my data source
Set ws = Sheet3
Set startCell = Range("C2")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = ws.Cells(startCell.Row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ws.Range(startCell, ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Select

'The cells I want to start populating
OppRow = Sheet2.Range("BL3").Row
OppClm = Sheet2.Range("BL3").Column

'Vlookup
For Each cl In ws
    Sheet2.Cells(OppRow, OppClm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(cl, ws, 6, False)
    OppRow = OppRow + 1
Next cl

End Sub
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to iterate? `ws` is a worksheet.  Do you want every cell on that sheet? or just column A?

Comment: I only want to select the relevant columns on ws, ideally the cells from columns C through H. The number of columns for the data source will be constant, but rows will be added and removed as the data changes.

Comment: The problem is less the error than the exact purpose of your loop. Describe precisely what you're trying to do. Also, the `Vlookup` function's first argument is what it will be looking for; it can't be `cl` which I assume you want to be a column in a range.